# Upgrade Windows Phone 7.5 to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, nokia, windows-phone-8

I am wanting to buy a Nokia Lumia 900 this week, it's (obviously) a Windows Phone 7.5, but Microsoft is going to release Windows 8/Windows Phone 8 somewhere in october and I am wondering if the Lumia will get an update to Windows Phone 8, and if it will not get an update, can I install Windows Phone 8 on my own?

Comment: This isnt the right site for such questions. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: [Will my phone be able to update to Windows Phone 8?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/676/will-my-phone-be-able-to-update-to-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You will get some of the UI changes brought in by Windows Phone 8 in the form of a WP7.8 update. Your lumia could run full WP8, but it wouldn't run it well, as the new WP8 devices, need stronger specs

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: Oh, I'm sorry! I didn't know about that. ;)
Besides that, I thank you for your answer and I think that I will have to wait on WP8 :)

Comment: @Louis: Thank you for your answer, I have read it and decided to wait with the purchase.

Answer (score 1):

No current generation Windows Phone will be able to be updated to Windows Phone 8 in a supported manner.  Who knows if you will be able to hack a copy onto it, though.  Current phones will receive an update to Windows Phone 7.8, which will have a similar start screen, but no other information has been released on that version yet.